# How do I fix a leaky outdoor faucet?

Tags: plumbing, repair, faucet, outdoor

As you can see, the outdoor faucet in my backyard leaks when the water is turned on. **It does not leak when the water is turned off.**  (For those who are wondering: Yes, there is *some* water going *through* the hose.)

So how do I fix this thing? I found [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hu6rCH7gmM) that shows how to tighten the packing nut, but that didn't work for me. Also, I can push/pull on the handle and it feels like the whole valve stem will come in/out about 1/4". This doesn't affect the amount of water that leaks though.

[image: Leaky Outdoor Faucet]

Comment: Does it leak when you turn it to "full blast"?

Answer (score 3):

[Woodford Faucet](http://www.woodfordfaucet.com/index.html) is probably the place to go for the parts breakdown if I can read the handle right. They produce a kit specifically for repair. You'll have to look for better identification, but here's the Model 17 kit (round handle) which probably addresses all the issues.

[image]

American MFG that's been around like forever and has always been good about repair kits. You'll recognize their key'd faucets if you've used campsites.

EPDM Packing that's under the Nut

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will get one of these repair kits and see what I can do. The videos at the website were very helpful. Hopefully it is as easy as it looks.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the packing sleeve gets so worn and/or hardened it does no good to tighten the packing nut to stop a leak. In the worst case the sleeve itself may even crack.

A fix for that is to remove the faucet handle and then the packing nut. It should then be possible to pick out the old packing sleeve and replace with a new one. You can get small kits of generic rubber faucet repair kits from various big box stores and hardware stores. With luck you can find a new packing nut of the proper size to squeeze down in by the stem of the faucet and press into place via the packing nut.